# Scaling CSS relative to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

Just wondering if theirs a more efficient means of doing this?

```
$(window).resize(function()                                                                   
{                                                                                             
    $('.title').css('font-size',Math.floor($(window).width()*0.2)+'px');                         
    $('.title').css('background-size',Math.floor($(window).width()*0.5)+'px');                   
    $('.title').css('padding',($(window).width()*0.1)+'px 0px '+($(window).width()*0.1)+'px');   
});  `
```

I'm doing this to get my web applicatiion (cordova/phonegap) to resize properly for all devices. I've tried using viewport and had mixed results especially when it came to getting text to scale relative to `dpi` and screen dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of doing this.
There are some pre-made libraries such as [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com) for mobile view.

You can use percentage instead modifying the css through jquery.

For some help a nice tutorial site for css is [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) css tutorial page.

Each result has different results.

---

Now on your example code you are using `window.width* 0.5` or `window.width / 2` which is half. If you are in the root element with no width settings you could use 50% instead of pixels to easily achieve the effect you are looking for.

However it is most likely not like that. You may have to specify widths of parent elements to achieve this.

Comment: This answer does not take in account of use of the cordova library you have tagged in question. I do not know this library so I am sorry to say but I do not know if there is an equivalent solution through that library. But The css Percentage usage is actually simple to use depending on how you developed your html.

Comment: That worked well for `background-image` but what about things like `font-size` ?

Comment: Percent will use the browsers default font width with the percentage applied to it if I read this correctly..

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

That should explain fonts a bit. Fonts may be a little different. It might be also best to try the @media css code that another answer has suggested for font sizes.

The BootStrap library makes use of that.

Answer (score 2):

have you considered using css @media .
it is more neat , and doesnt require javascript event to be triggered.

more info can be found here
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: Will this scale my elements exactly in proportion with the screen dimensions?

Comment: indeed , as long as you define these elemetns css  corresponding to each resolution , it is like saying if ( current resolution == "whatever" ) {load the following css();}

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media queries to serve the purpose.